# Getting an error when installing the .Net 5 Runtime on Armbian (on an Orange Pi Zero)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, .net-5, orange-pi

I'm trying to install the .Net 5 Runtime on Armbian Focal (Ubuntu 20.04) or Buster (Debian 10), running on an Orange Pi Zero.

So I followed Microsoft's instructions here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu

but on the last step:

```
sudo apt-get install -y aspnetcore-runtime-5.0
```

I get this error:

```
E: Unable to locate package aspnetcore-runtime-5.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'aspnetcore-runtime-5.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'aspnetcore-runtime-5.0'
```

I then followed Microsoft's suggestion for installing it manually from here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#apt-troubleshooting

But on the last step, again I get the same error.
Any ideas?

In summary, these are the steps I tried first:

```
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.10/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo apt-get update; \
  sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && \
  sudo apt-get update && \
  sudo apt-get install -y aspnetcore-runtime-5.0
```

and these are the steps I tried when the above failed:

```
sudo dpkg --purge packages-microsoft-prod && sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y gpg
wget -O - https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor -o microsoft.asc.gpg
sudo mv microsoft.asc.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/{os-version}/prod.list
sudo mv prod.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list
sudo chown root:root /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.asc.gpg
sudo chown root:root /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list
sudo apt-get update; \
  sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && \
  sudo apt-get update && \
  sudo apt-get install -y aspnetcore-runtime-5.0
```

**EDIT:**

*I've previously installed the .Net Core 3.1 Runtime on this exact same setup without any issues. I'm not sure if there is something in .Net 5 that is different which won't allow me to install it*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the first URL you linked: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu

> Package manager installs are only supported on the x64 architecture. Other architectures, such as ARM, must install .NET by some other means such as with Snap, an installer script, or through a manual binary installation.

A Pi is an ARM device, so the installation method you are trying to use is not supported.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in this response. Yes, you were 100% correct. Thank you.